# How do I write a folder created by me on google drive

Tags: ios8, google-drive-api, xcode6

I was asked to write the files sent to the Google Drive account to a pre-defined folder created with the code below

```
(void) createGoogleFolder
{
    GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folder.title = @"ICA Voice Memo";
    folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
   [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                              NSError *error) {
   if (error != nil)
   {
      NSString *err = error;
   }
   }];

}
```

My code for writing a mp4 file t Google drive is below

```
-(void) writeToGoogleDrive:(NSString *)modifiedFileDateString
{
    [self createGoogleFolder];
    NSString *title = modifiedFileDateString;

    GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
    metadata.title = title;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:modifiedFileDateString];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0 error:&error];
    if(data != nil && error==nil) {
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"audio/mp4"];
        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:metadata uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
        [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                              NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            UIAlertView *alert =
            [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Upload Error"
                                       message: [error localizedDescription]
                                      delegate: nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

I want to write the data to the new folder created on the Google drive 'ICA Voice Memo'.

How do I amend my code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked it out after a couple of days. Firstly I have a method which checks for the existence of a folder using the current folder Id, if it is blank I use the code below

```
-(void) createGoogleFolder
{
    GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folder.title = @"ICA Voice Memo";
    folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFolder,
                                              NSError *error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            uploadFolderID =  updatedFolder.identifier;

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *docDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *path = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Cloud.plist"];

            NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

            [data setObject:uploadFolderID forKey:@"GoogleFolderID"];

            [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

After which I use the folder Id as my parent id and add the file in the normal way.